# Perform cartesian to polar transformation of image while preserving intensity

Tags: python

If anybody can offer some help on this I would greatly appreciate it.
I am trying to take an image where I will specify an origin coordinate and then do a polar transformation to it and output an image. I tried this with the skimage library with the following code:

'''

```
    def cart2polar(im, center):
     image=io.imread(im)
     #warped = warp_polar(image, (100,100), radius=100,output_shape=image.shape, scaling='log')
     warped = warp_polar(image, center,scaling='linaer')
     #saved polar converted image
     newName=im[0:len(im)-5]+"_warped.tiff"
     io.imsave(newName,warped)
     return warped
```

'''
This does everything I want after I print the image using plotly express or matplotlib, but I have 2 major issues that result from the images.

1. The intensity values are not preserved. They have been scaled to be between 0:0.35 from 0:40,0000. (this is the higher priority issue)
2. I cannot open the image in windows 10 for some reason. The original image can be viewed in windows 10 viewer. (not too important if can't be solved)

**EDIT**

So I have opened the image in imagej and it seems that it converted the original 16bit image into a 32bit image. I don't know if this offers any insight for someone to offer me some advice.

Comment: have you tried saving into another format?